# How to scale data for every iterations in GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, machine-learning, audio, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I'm working in a ML project that classifies patients from healthy subjects using speaking voice files. I want to search for the best parameters of the SVC classifier using GridSearchCV. Currently I split my data into the ratio of 3:1:1.

The problem is there are several voice files from each subject, which means that there are high possibilities of data leakage if I simply feed all of my train/validation data into GridSearchCV. This solution can be solved by manually split the dataset beforehand and using PredefinedSplit. But I couldn't find the way to scale the data before split them by PredefinedSplit yet.

My current pipeline is:

Manually split dataset -> Tag them using PredefinedSplit -> Find the best parameter from every fold using GridSearchCV

What I want is:

Manually split dataset -> Tag them using PredefinedSplit -> **Scale the data using StandardScaler()** -> Find the best parameter from every fold using GridSearchCV

I'm not really sure that Pipeline() will work or not though. If I understand it correctly, using

```
Pipeline(steps=[("scaler", StandardScaler(), ("gridsearch", GridSearchCV(estimator = SVC()])
```

will scale all the data then feed it into GridSearchCV.

Here's the method of scaling data if I understand it correctly

```
SC = StandardScaler()
train = SC.fit_transform(train)
val = SC.transform(val)
test = SC.transform(test)
```

My goal to scale the data using this method for every iteration of GridSearchCV, which train/val dataset is controlled by PredefinedSplit test_fold value.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about `Pipeline`, but just changing the order of the grid search and the pipeline works the way you want it to:

```py
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
    ("scaler", StandardScaler()),
    ("model", SVC()),
])
search = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, ...)
```

This now fits the pipeline for every hyperparameter/fold combination, and in particular the scaler gets fitted on each training fold and applied (without refitting) to test folds.

Since the scaler will get refitted on the same training fold for each hyperparameter, you might want to consider the `cache` parameter of `Pipeline`.